# What's the most elegant way to get the end of the day (datetime)?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm currently writing some reporting code that allows users to optionally specify a date range. The way it works (simplified), is:

- A user (optionally) specifies a year.
- A user (optionally) specifies a month.
- A user (optionally) specifies a day.

Here's a code snippet, along with comments describing what I'd **like** to do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# ...

now = datetime.now()
start_time = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
stop_time = now
# If the user enters no year, month, or day--then we'll simply run a
# report that only spans the current day (from the start of today to now).

if options['year']:
    start_time = start_time.replace(year=options['year'], month=0, day=0)
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(year=options['year'])
    # If the user specifies a year value, we should set stop_time to the last
    # day / minute / hour / second / microsecond of the year, that way we'll
    # only generate reports from the start of the specified year, to the end
    # of the specified year.

if options['month']:
    start_time = start_time.replace(month=options['month'], day=0)
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(month=options['month'])
    # If the user specifies a month value, then set stop_time to the last
    # day / minute / hour / second / microsecond of the specified month, that
    # way we'll only generate reports for the specified month.

if options['day']:
    start_time = start_time.replace(day=options['day'])
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(day=options['day'])
    # If the user specifies a day value, then set stop_time to the last moment of
    # the current day, so that reports ONLY run on the current day.
```

I'm trying to find the most elegant way to write the code above--I've been trying to find a way to do it with timedelta, but can't seem to figure it out. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The end of any given day would always be `23:59:59.999`

Comment: @MarcB That's not true during leap seconds, which are at 23:59:60.

Comment: True, but then it's easy enough to add in checks for June/Dec - they're rare enough to not be a concern for most systems. Or adjust the date logic to be `< tomorrow:00:00:00` instead of `<= today:23:59:59`

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at some of the answers here, and not really finding anything extremely elegant, I did some poking around the standard library and found my current solution (which I like quite well): `dateutil`.

Here's how I implemented it:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

now = date.today()
stop_time = now + relativedelta(days=1)
start_time = date(
    # NOTE: I'm not doing dict.get() since in my implementation, these dict
    # keys are guaranteed to exist.
    year = options['year'] or now.year,
    month = options['month'] or now.month,
    day = options['day'] or now.day
)

if options['year']:
    start_time = date(year=options['year'] or now.year, month=1, day=1)
    stop_time = start_time + relativedelta(years=1)

if options['month']:
    start_time = date(
        year = options['year'] or now.year,
        month = options['month'] or now.month,
        day = 1
    )
    stop_time = start_time + relativedelta(months=1)

if options['day']:
    start_time = date(
        year = options['year'] or now.year,
        month = options['month'] or now.month,
        day = options['day'] or now.day,
    )
    stop_time = start_time + relativedelta(days=1)

# ... do stuff with start_time and stop_time here ...
```

What I like about this implementation, is that python's `dateutil.relativedata.relativedata` works really well on edge cases. It gets the days/months/years correct. If I have `month=12`, and do `relativedata(months=1)`, it'll increment the year and set the month to 1 (works nicely).

Also: in the above implementation, if the user specifies none of the optional dates (year, month, or day)--we'll fallback to a nice default (start_time = this morning, stop_time = tonight), that way we'll default to doing stuff for the current day only.

Thanks to everyone for their answers--they were helpful in my research.

Answer (score 6):

To set the `stop_time`, advance `start_time` one year, month or day as appropriate, then subtract one `timedelta(microseconds=1)`

```
if options['year']:
    start_time = start_time.replace(year=options['year'], month=1, day=1)
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(year=options['year']+1)-timedelta(microseconds=1)

elif options['month']:
    start_time = start_time.replace(month=options['month'], day=1)
    months=options['month']%12+1
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(month=months,day=1)-timedelta(microseconds=1)

else:
    start_time = start_time.replace(day=options['day'])
    stop_time = stop_time.replace(day=options['day'])+timedelta(days=1,microseconds=-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `dict.get` can simplify your code.  It is a bit cleaner than using *datetime.replace* and *timedelta* objects.

Here's something to get you started:

```
from datetime import datetime

options = dict(month=5, day=20)
now = datetime.now()
start_time = datetime(year=options.get('year', now.year), 
                      month=options.get('month', 1),
                      day=options.get('day', 1)
                      hour=0,
                      minute=0,
                      second=0)
stop_time =  datetime(year=options.get('year', now.year), 
                      month=options.get('month', now.month),
                      day=options.get('day', now.day),
                      hour=now.hour,
                      minute=now.minute,
                      second=now.second)
```

Comment: This was helpful, however, after playing around, I found dateutil.relativedelta to be more elegant. I updated my answer with that method incase you have any feedback.

Answer (score 5):

```
    today = datetime.date.today()
    begintime = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
    endtime = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

def get_current_timestamp():
    return int(datetime.now().timestamp())

def get_end_today_timestamp():
    # get 23:59:59
    result = datetime.combine(date.today() + timedelta(days=1), datetime.min.time())
    return int(result.timestamp()) - 1

def get_datetime_from_timestamp(timestamp):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

end_today = get_datetime_from_timestamp(get_end_today_timestamp())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = datetime.strftime('<input date str>')

date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)  # now we get begin of the day
date += timedelta(days=1, microseconds=-1)  # now end of the day
```