# Get the last day of next month in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, monthcalendar

How to calculate the last day of next month or next 4 months in Python?

I tried datetime, however, it does not support opperation of +.

To reopen my question.

```
    datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.datetime.date(2019,4,20).month
```

this is helpful because if I want to get the last day of next 4 months from 2019-12-30. Then the year will change too.

I want to reopen this because one of the answers is surprising. I did not know np can output dates. Cool answer.

Comment: Hello, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. We cannot help without code. What have you tried? SO is not here to do the coding for you, but we are very willing to help solve a specific coding problem.

Comment: `datetime` *does* support straightforward date math.  Recheck the documentation.  Look for `timedelta`.  Advance to the first day of the following month, then subtract a day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the most elegant way to get the end of the day (datetime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985756/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-get-the-end-of-the-day-datetime)

Comment: you can get current date `today = datetime.date.today()`, use `today.month`, `today.year` to calculate 2 months later and create first day `first_day = datetime.date(year, month, 1)` and substract one day `last_day = first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Guys, if you don't have a clue. Just leave my post. Why did you try to close it??? There are tons of people smarter than you (so called experienced community members). Is it too hard for you to accept the fact that you don't know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```py
import numpy as np

# display last day of Dezember, 2019
print(np.arange('2019-12', '2020-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')[-1])

# add a month to Dezemeber, 2019
np.datetime64('2019-12') + np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Comment: This is cool, I did not know you can output dates in np. Thank you!!!